# can you build apps with xcode 3.2.4 and submit to apple?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, submission

hi i have a project built with the 4.1 sdk, I dont have that current sdk. So i am going to download it.

The thing is on the apple website, it says download xcode 3.2.4 with 4.1 sdk.

Can you built applications with xcode 3.2.4? and then can you send it to apple for submission? or will it not go through submission as xcode 3.2.4 is still under beta? can someone please tell me as i dont want to waste time downloading it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you built applications with xcode 3.2.4?

Yes.

> and then can you send it to apple for submission?

Yes.

> or will it not go through submission as xcode 3.2.4 is still under beta?

No.

> can someone please tell me as i dont want to waste time downloading it.

3.2.4 is not a "beta" -- it is the latest release. You might be mixing up the iOS SDK (of which 4.1 is the latest release, and 4.2 is the beta) with Xcode proper.

Apple tests apps against the latest stable release version of the SDK, which currently is 4.1.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thank you for answering my questions and clearing up my concerns.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.1__final/xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1.dmg

Is the current build, for accepted apps.

Comment: ok so just to make sure if i program for this app using this xcode 3.2.4 and sdk 4.1 all of my apps that i submit can be actually put forward to apple? and if it everything is successful they wont mind accepting the app?